# Calculate the number of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Suppose that $A$ is an abelian group with order $p^4$ where $p$ is a prime number. And there exists a subgroup $N$ such that $A/N\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$. Calculate the number of $A$ satisfies the condition above?

I think due to the abelian group structure theorem, there could be only five kinds of abelian group with order $p^4$:

$\mathbb{Z}/p^4\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times/\mathbb{Z}p^3\mathbb{Z}$

$\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\times/\mathbb{Z}p^2\mathbb{Z}$.

So I think the answer is two since we can take $N=p^3\mathbb{Z}/p^4\mathbb{Z}$ in the first condition and the forth condition is obvious.

For the rest of them, there is no element with order larger than $p^2$.

Comment: Can you list all the abelian groups (up to isomorphism) of order $p^4$ without further restrictions? Because that is a prerequisite exercise for the one you have here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct.

The assumption that a quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ forces the group to have an element of order at least $p^3$. Since the group is a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups, the only way for this is that one of the factors is $\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^4\mathbb{Z}$.